# Disable TextInput Object

Tags: vba, ms-word, textinput, disabled-input

I have a `checkbox` and if the `checkbox.Value = False` I want to disable my TextInput-Object. On the internet there where some suggestions, but the methods which were used are not working for me, because the methods are not found.

I tried it with the `.Valid`-method:

```
Dim tf As TextInput
Dim checkbox As CheckBox

Sub checkbox_click()

Set checkbox = ActiveDocument.FormFields("checkbox").CheckBox
Set tf = ActiveDocument.FormFields("textfield").TextInput

If checkbox.Value = False

    tf.Valid = False
End If

End Sub
```

But that doesn't work for some reason. I found `tf.Enabled = False` on the internet, but this method is unknown in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something more like this:

```
Dim ff As FormField
Dim checkbox As CheckBox
.
.
Set checkbox = ActiveDocument.FormFields("checkbox").CheckBox
Set ff = ActiveDocument.FormFields("textfield")

If checkbox.Value = False
  ff.Enabled = False
End If
```

With legacy FormField objects, some of the properties you need are associated with the FormField itself, and others are associated with child objects of the FormField such as the FormField.Checkbox

So the problem here is that `tf` is a `FormField.TextInput` object, but `.Enabled` is a property of the `FormField` object.

Not relevant to your question, but just as an observation, FormFields do not have Word events associated with them in the normal sense of VBA Events. The settings of each field tell Word to run a named Sub "on entry" and/or  "on exit" - that's it. No actual click events. No problem with using names that makes those things look like events but I just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the internet can be helpful you should also use the Object Browser in the VBE along with Help. 5 seconds spent doing a search for FormField would have given you the answer.

```
Dim tf As TextInput
Dim checkbox As CheckBox

Sub checkbox_click()

Set checkbox = ActiveDocument.FormFields("checkbox").CheckBox

If checkbox.Value = False
    ActiveDocument.FormFields("textfield").Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```